# Right to Left (RTL) text in polybar

Tags: linux, arch-linux, statusbar

I'm using [Polybar](https://github.com/polybar/polybar), and I want to show a Persian text on it. According to the docs on [text module](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Module:-text), I can achieve this like this:

```
[module/persian]
type = custom/text
content = یک متن فارسی
```

And then I can use this module like this:

```
modules-left = bspwm
modules-center = date
modules-right = persian battery
```

But the result is this:

[image: polybar ltr]

As you can see, the text is reversed (is shown LTR). It should look like the way it's shown in the terminal.

I tried adding a RTL override character (`U+202E`):

[image: polybar rtl character]

But that doesn't work either, as it produces this warning:

```
warn: Dropping unmatched character  (U+202e)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I fix this?

Short answer: You can't.

---

Slightly longer answer:

Polybar does all its text rendering on its own, character by character, it doesn't have any fancy toolkit behind it.

Because of that it only has rudimentary support for UTF-8 any doesn't support any kind of compound or control characters.
That means for example it doesn't support the RTL override character or things like emoji skin tone modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fribidi` to render RTL texts. Here is an example of my polybar Jalali module:

```sh
[module/jdate]
type = custom/script
exec = "jdate "+%d %V" | fribidi | sed 's/  //g;s/0/۰/g;s/1/۱/g;s/2/۲/g;s/3/۳/g;s/4/۴/g;s/5/۵/g;s/6/۶/g;s/7/۷/g;s/8/۸/g;s/9/۹/g'"
tail = true
interval = 60
format = <label>
format-prefix = "%{F#dd7878} "
format-prefix-foreground = ${colors.foreground}
label = %output:0:50%
```

To match the missing characters you should define a supported font in
`bar` module:

```sh
[bar/example]
...
font-0 = Manrope:pixelsize=11;2
font-1 = Vazirmatn UI: pixelsize=11;0
font-2 = iMWritingDuospace Nerd Font::pixelsize=12;2
```

The result:

[image: The result]